# can't buy bitcoin eBook using bitcoin?

Tags: ecommerce

It sounds like a headline from The Onion, but is it really true?  I can't find anywhere I can buy the eBook Mastering Bitcoin using bitcoin, only PayPal or Credit Card.

Answer (score 1):

He suspended sales because the original print run ran out. The merchants that accept paypal/credit cards are only accepting preorders.

He posts availability info on his website:

https://www.bitcoinbook.info/

In the meantime, he's [published the book online.](https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook)

Comment: What does the print run have to do with eBooks?  My question is about the eBook.  The link you provided is to the raw, initial release, not the final version.

Comment: Quote from the website I linked: `Our bitcoin sale received overwhelming response, so we have temporarily suspended direct sales while we work with O’Reilly Media on fulfillment via bitcoin.`